# C# MongoDb Driver Gte Filter

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core

I want to display the ones after the date filter that I gave using MongoDb Driver. But it comes in the date in the filter.

```
var client = new MongoClient(conn);
var filter = Builders<DefaultLogs>.Filter;
var database = client.GetDatabase(db);
var collection = database.GetCollection<DefaultLogs>(coll);

var client2 = new MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017");
var database2 = client2.GetDatabase("assetLogsLocalDb");
var collection2 = database2.GetCollection<Config>("config");
var configData = collection2.Find(_=>true).FirstOrDefault();
```

Query

```
var query = filter.Gte(x => x.RecordDate, new BsonDateTime(configData.RecordDate)) & filter.Eq(x => x.MethodName, "LogInformation") & filter.Type(x => x.LogText, "string");
```

What I want is the greater than the date. Not more than or equal to

Comment: Use `.Gt` instead of `.Gte`?